# Populate data in a Select component from Material UI v1 beta

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to populate data from a **< Select >** component from Material UI v 1.0.0.0 beta but it's not working.

This is part of my code:

This is inside the render() method.

```
        <Select
          value={this.state.DivisionState}
          onChange={this.handleChangeDivision}
        >
          {this.renderDivisionOptions()}
        </Select>
```

And here I use the MenuItem tag to populate de value coming from a WS

```
  renderDivisionOptions() {
    return this.state.DivisionData.map((dt, i) => {
      return (
        <MenuItem
          key={i}
          value={dt.divDeptShrtDesc}>
        </MenuItem>
      );
    });
  }
```

This was working in the latest version of Material UI using the DropDown tag and MenuItem ej. "**< DropDown > < MenuItem >.....**"

Some help will be nice.

Regards

I'm getting and error when I try to interact with the Select component..

[image]

Comment: Could you give error messsge?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: How is `this.state.DivisionData` set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add display value `dt.divDeptShrtDesc` for Items:

```
renderDivisionOptions() {
        return this.state.DivisionData.map((dt, i) => {
          return (
            <MenuItem
              key={i}
              value={dt.divDeptShrtDesc}>
                {dt.divDeptShrtDesc}
            </MenuItem>
          );
        });
      }
```

Small demo for using `Seclect` of `material-ui` (v1.0.0): https://codesandbox.io/s/5voz6y7kwl
Hope it's useful for you

Comment: Thanks for your time, now I can see the first option from the WS in the select component but when I try to change the option to validate it's ok, I got the error I put in the above Image

Comment: Could you show all your code? Your error is similar with https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/8190. Could you try upgrade `material-ui` to latest version?